# Error comes up when creating controller for ASP.Net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-apicontroller

I have just created a ASP.NET web API project with Visual Studio 17 and I have created a Class Library to connect it to an SQL database I created. the problem is when I try to create a controller in the project, I get the error,

> There was an error running the selected code generator: could not load file 'ClassLibrary.dll' or one of it's dependencies. this system could not find the file specified.

Does anyone what the problem could be. I have looked at the folder where the said file should be contained in the ClassLibrary and it is empty.

I gather that it might be from my Entity Framework, I am using ADO.Net Entity Data Model.

Comment: check Framework version for these projects

Comment: You might also want to just close & reopen visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.NET web API project no need to add Class Library:

- Just right click in Solution and add ADO.net Model
- Configure with Database
- Add required Database Tables
- Build solution

Answer (score 1):

First you have to add reference of your class library project if you don't then  just  give a built to your project in which you added a reference of class library project, then try to create a controller it will definitely help you....

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.